# Why all TextBoxes in ItemsControl use the last dynamically-added ValidationRule?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties, itemscontrol

I have a custom TextBox that adds `MinMaxValidationRule` when both `Min` and `Max` properties are set

```
public class TextBox2 : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Min), typeof(double?), typeof(TextBox2),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, MinMaxChangeCallback));

    public double? Min
    {
        get => (double?)GetValue(MinProperty);
        set => SetValue(MinProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Max), typeof(double?), typeof(TextBox2),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, MinMaxChangeCallback));

    public double? Max
    {
        get => (double?)GetValue(MaxProperty);
        set => SetValue(MaxProperty, value);
    }

    private static void MinMaxChangeCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox2 = (TextBox2)d;
        if (textBox2.Min == null || textBox2.Max == null)
            return;
        var binding = textBox2.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
        var validationRules = binding
            .ParentBinding
            .ValidationRules;
        validationRules.Clear();
        var minMaxValidationRule = new MinMaxValidationRule((double)textBox2.Min, (double)textBox2.Max)
        {
            ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = true
        };
        validationRules.Add(minMaxValidationRule);
        binding.UpdateTarget(); // triggers the validation rule
    }
}
```

The validation rule is defined as follows

```
public class MinMaxValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public double Min { get; }
    public double Max { get; }

    public MinMaxValidationRule(double min, double max)
    {
        Min = min;
        Max = max;
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (double.TryParse((string)value, out var d)
            && d <= Max
            && d >= Min)
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;

        return new ValidationResult(false, $"Value must be in [{Min},{Max}]");
    }
}
```

I've created a ItemsControl to display a list of `ItemInfo` objects

```
<ItemsControl
    Margin="8"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ItemInfos}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testApp:ItemInfo}">
            <testApp:TextBox2
                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
                Width="400"
                Margin="12"
                Padding="8"
                Min="{Binding Min}"
                Max="{Binding Max}"
                Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ItemInfos = new()
        {
            new()
            {
                Min = 0,
                Max = 100,
                Value = 50
            },
            new()
            {
                Min = 200,
                Max = 300,
                Value = 250
            },
        };
    }

    public List<ItemInfo> ItemInfos { get; }
}

public class ItemInfo
{
    public double Min { get; set; }
    public double Max { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

When writing "2" in the first TextBox (changing the value from 50 to 502), WPF is using the validation rule of the second textBox, but I expect that each TextBox uses its own ValidationRule.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image: Demo of the actual behaviour]

Comment: I am guessing that since the validation rule is applied to the Binding of the DataTemplate it is shared by the two TextBoxes but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This seems to be a known limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10325407/13448212) when using Templates.
There is a workaround to this, by using another override of `Validate` of the ValidationRule so that you can access the control and the updated value.

You can edit the MinMaxValidationRule class as follow

```
public class MinMaxValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public MinMaxValidationRule()
    {
        ValidatesOnTargetUpdated = true;
    }
    
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo, BindingExpressionBase owner)
    {
        // This will be the actual validation (use the BindingExpressionBase to get acess to the TextBox2 control)
        var textBox2 = (TextBox2)owner.Target;
        if (textBox2.Min != null
            && textBox2.Max != null
            && double.TryParse((string)value, out var d) is var b
            && (!b || d > textBox2.Max || d < textBox2.Min)
           )
            return new ValidationResult(false, $"Value must be in [{textBox2.Min},{textBox2.Max}]");
        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;        
    }
}
```

Now since we read the current value of the Min and Max property, you don't need the `MinMaxChangeCallback` so you can just add the Validation rule on the loaded event.

```
public TextBox2()
{
    this.Loaded += TextBox2_Loaded;
}

private void TextBox2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var binding = this.GetBindingExpression(TextProperty);
    var validationRules = binding
        .ParentBinding
        .ValidationRules;
    validationRules.Clear();
    var minMaxValidationRule = new MinMaxValidationRule();
    validationRules.Add(minMaxValidationRule);
    binding.UpdateTarget(); // triggers the validation rule
}
```

Comment: Great, your solution is different, not like the one suggested by KoenJ.. When setting `ValidationStep = ValidationStep.UpdatedValue;` in `MinMaxValidationRule` ctor, the `object value` will be the BindingExpression (from which you can access the TextBox2 instance), but the issue is that when I want to `double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out var d)`, the value of `textBox2.Text` is the old one (i.e 50), not the new one (i.e 502).. This is solved with the override approach you've suggested, Where I'm getting the Min/Max from BindingExpression and the updated text (i.e 502) from `object value`.

Comment: @Muhammad Sulaiman : Well he does mention getting the BindingExpression into the ValidationRule then dealing with its state to make the validation (though I didn't investigate the link with `ValidationStep.UpdatedValue`). Anyway I am glad that my answer helped you :)